# Android market keyword search hits query

Tags: android, google-play, keyword

I would like to know if tere is any way to see how many times a keyword is searched on the Android Market

For example, if I build an educational app, say math operations, can I see
How many times this exact phrase is searched so I can name it Math or Basic Algrbra instead.

Just want to know that a keyword "XYZ" has been searched X times in Android market.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Google provides with this information. You can get the top search keyworks on AppBrain: http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-search-terms

However you can check the global trends for any keywords searched on Google. This could serve as an indication of how much they are searched in the market:

http://www.google.com/trends/?q=XYZ

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes it can give a fair idea of search numbers against a keyword but I was looking for something specific to Android Market.